# Zooming in and zooming out in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I wanted to implement into my jQuery site option to zoom in and zoom out. This site uses a lot of [jQueryUI Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) elements (even like one of top of the other) and everything is working just fine, until I try to add a scaling option into it. The only way I tried is using `-webkit-transform: scale(0.5)` and it totally ruined all my draggables. The handles had wrong clip box and were almost unusable. Moreover, a whole page is being messed by this `transform` thing.

It looks way better when I use the browser built-in `Ctrl` + `+ / -` option. It works just like I want it to work **BUT** the draggable area isn't the only thing on this site. The UI surrounding my area are getting smaller/bigger as well with the rest of the site.

I'm looking for a solution of zooming in and zooming out on my **one div**. I'm using jQuery only (because of my site structure limitations) so I'm not going to add any canvas areas to it.

If there's more info needed, just ask. I tried to mention every single important detail.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot for you to understand my page structure:
[image]

All UI elements are `fixed` on the site and the draggable center area is `absolute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want that image to be zoomed on mouse hover :**

$(document).ready( function() {
$('#div img').hover(

```
function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1.2 }, 400);
},
function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 400);
});
```

});

**​or you may do like this if zoom in and out buttons are used :**

$("#ZoomIn").click(ZoomIn());

$("#ZoomOut").click(ZoomOut());

function ZoomIn (event) {

```
$("#div img").width(
    $("#div img").width() * 1.2
);

$("#div img").height(
    $("#div img").height() * 1.2
);
```

},

function  ZoomOut (event) {

```
$("#div img").width(
    $("#imgDtls").width() * 0.5
);

$("#div img").height(
    $("#div img").height() * 0.5
);
```

}

Comment: I'm zooming in a `div` and its entire content, not the width of it, because it would ruin my draggable areas, so that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I mixed your answer with an other solution I found online and got a buggy, but so far working prototype.

Answer (score 1):

### Try using http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element").click(function(evt) {
        $(this).zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried way too hard to make this work. Unfortunately, Zoomooz.js is using the `transform` thing and gives the same, but animated, output. Not what I'm looking for either.